# Blackduck scan results into GPL exception license risks in my android project. Can anyone provide the ways to fix this issue?

Tags: android, classpath, blackduck

I am observing GPL2 class path exception in my android project in the components Codenameone . I am not using any codenameone library still the risks is there. I am not sure from where exactly it is coming from. Can anyone help here? See the screenshot attached for the issue.[image]